# Nonclustered columstore Index memory allocation

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

We are planning to use a non-clustered columnstore index on 30 nvarchar(100) columns. The table can have rows ranging from a few hundreds to millions. These columns are selected during query execution and based on our customer's requirements, can also be part of the where clause or order by.

The memory allocated consumed by sql using column store index is excessive around 786 mb, whereas the utilized memory is just 6 MB. Is there any way to minimize the excessive memory grant?

We do not see excessive memory utilization with row index but where and order clauses in the sql are dynamically generated so we can't use.

Execution Plan : Please find the plan @ https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r19uMEE02

Execution plan image:

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT CREATION_TIME, START_TIME, FINISH_TIME, JOB_STATUS, 
        JOB.VERSION, JOB.JOB_ID, JOB.PROCESS_ID, JOB.SKIN_ID, LANGUAGE, JOB.BUDGET, JOB.EXPECTED_COST,  JOB.SPEND_SO_FAR , JOB.PRIORITY , JOB.TYPE , 
AW_RESOURCE.RESOURCE_NAME , CASE_INSTANCE.CASE_REFERENCE , JOB.PROCESS_NAME , KNOWN_SERVERS.SERVER_NAME , JOB.SLA_STATUS2_DATE,JOB.SLA_STATUS3_DATE,JOB.SLA_STATUS4_DATE,JOB.SLA_STATUS5_DATE ,JOB.STATE , JOB.EXPECTED_FINISH_TIME , JOB.CUST_DATA, JOB.SCORE ,JOB.JOB_OWNER_ID,OWNER.RESOURCE_NAME , BUSINESS_PROCESS_STATE.STATE_PERCENT ,

LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD1VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD2VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD3VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD4VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD5VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD6VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD7VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD8VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD9VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD10VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD11VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD12VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD13VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD14VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD15VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD16VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD17VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD18VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD19VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD20VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD21VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD22VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD23VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD24VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD25VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD26VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD27VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD28VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD29VALUE, LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.FIELD30VALUE, JOB.SUSPEND_REASON , AW_RESOURCE.RESOURCE_ID, AW_RESOURCE.PROFILE_PICTURE_FILENAME AS CREATOR_PROFILE_PIC,OWNER.PROFILE_PICTURE_FILENAME AS OWNER_PROFILE_PIC 
FROM  {oj JOB WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN AW_RESOURCE WITH (NOLOCK) ON JOB.CREATOR = AW_RESOURCE.RESOURCE_ID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN AW_RESOURCE OWNER WITH (NOLOCK) ON JOB.JOB_OWNER_ID = OWNER.RESOURCE_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BUSINESS_PROCESS WITH (NOLOCK) ON JOB.PROCESS_ID = BUSINESS_PROCESS.PROCESS_ID AND JOB.VERSION = BUSINESS_PROCESS.VERSION 
LEFT OUTER JOIN KNOWN_SERVERS WITH (NOLOCK) ON JOB.ORIGIN_SERVER_ID = KNOWN_SERVERS.SERVER_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CASE_INSTANCE WITH (NOLOCK) ON JOB.ASSOCIATED_CASE_ID = CASE_INSTANCE.JOB_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BUSINESS_PROCESS_STATE WITH (NOLOCK) ON JOB.PROCESS_ID = BUSINESS_PROCESS_STATE.PROCESS_ID AND JOB.VERSION = BUSINESS_PROCESS_STATE.VERSION AND JOB.STATE = BUSINESS_PROCESS_STATE.STATE 
},
LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION WITH (NOLOCK)  
WHERE  JOB.TYPE <>3  AND JOB_STATUS NOT IN (1, 2, 14, 9, 8, 10, 13, 15, 11 ) AND JOB.VERSION <>0  
 AND DEFINITION_NAME = @WQDefNameFilter  AND JOB.JOB_ID = LIVE_WORK_QUEUE_DEFINITION.JOBID 
AND ( FIELD1VALUE = N'1' AND FIELD19VALUE = N'19' AND FIELD30VALUE = N'30' AND FIELD15VALUE = N'15' )
ORDER BY EXPECTED_FINISH_TIME
```

Please find the plan at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkWnb5aa2.

We need to support SQL Server 2016 up to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your SQL Servers to the latest cumulative update.

- This is CU22 for [SQL Server 2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=100809) at the time of writing. You are currently using RTM (with only crucial security fixes applied).
- For [SQL Server 2022](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=105013) it is CU7.

For **SQL Server 2017 and later**, your batch mode execution plans can benefit from [memory grant feedback](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/intelligent-query-processing-feedback#memory-grant-feedback). This will adjust the memory grant over repeated executions until it finds a stable value.

For **SQL Server 2016**, you may need to attach [`MIN_GRANT_PERCENT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query#min_grant_percent--numeric_value) and/or [`MAX_GRANT_PERCENT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query#max_grant_percent--numeric_value) query hints. This is also an option for 2017 and later if your workload isn't suitable for memory grant feedback.

See the linked documentation for details.

In general, it is unreasonable to expect accurate memory grants for every possible complicated query submitted by your customers, for all possible table sizes.

You may find specifying sensible minimum and maximum grant percentages is the most optimal solution for your case. Memory grant feedback works when the same query is executed more than once. If your workload consists of many one-off executions, it will not help much, if at all.

If you use variables in your one-off queries, you may find you get better results with an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint. This generates a plan for the current values of parameters and variables in most cases and does not cache the plan for reuse.

Or you may find you're worrying about a *potential* problem that will not manifest in reality. The example SQL Server 2022 execution plan runs for a grand total of **172ms**. In other words, more memory than necessary is tied up for under 0.2s. This could be a problem in some contexts, but entirely unnoticeable in others.

#### Other advice

Remove all the `NOLOCK` hints from your query. If you really want to read uncommitted data, use the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level instead. The `NOLOCK` hint is not a magic go-faster switch.

Check you really need the final `ORDER BY` clause, or if rows can be sorted at the client. Alternatively, select the small result set into a temporary table and then sort that. This should produce a more accurate initial grant.

Comment: as you suggested we  have installed   SQL Server® 2022 Latest Cumulative Update . After the installation, excessive memory allocation issue is resolved. Now memory grant is 9216 KB. Do you how cumulative install can impact memory grant ?

Comment: Cumulative Updates fix product bugs and can include general improvements. I don't know why it helped in your case.